# PowerShell Remoting with Kerberos Authentication (KeyTab based)

Tags: powershell, kerberos, windows-authentication, cpu-usage, powershell-remoting

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
$OutputFile  = $args[0]
$UserID   = $args[1]
$Domain   = $args[2]

$filePath = "output.log"

if (Test-Path $filePath) {
    # Delete the file
    Remove-Item $filePath
}

Start-Transcript -Path $filePath -Append

Write-Host "Staring PowerShell script"
Write-Host "outFile: $OutputFile"
Write-Host "UserID : $UserID"
Write-Host "domain : $domain"

$env:KRB5CCNAME="C:\Users\$UserID\krb5cache"
& "C:\Program Files\MIT\Kerberos\bin\klist" -s
& "${env:JAVA_HOME}bin\kinit.exe" -k -t c:\users\$UserID\$UserID.keytab $UserID@$Domain.COM

$remoteMachine = "remoteMachine@domain.com"
$keytabPath = "c:\users\$UserID\$UserID.keytab"

$cachePath = $env:KRB5CCNAME

$cacheContent = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $cachePath -Encoding Byte))
    
$ticketBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cacheContent)

$secureString = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
foreach ($char in [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetChars($ticketBytes)) {
    $secureString.AppendChar($char)
}

$userPrincipal = "$UserID@$Domain.COM" 

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userPrincipal, $secureString)

if ($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Error: Unable to create PSCredential object. Please check the secure string and try again."
}
else {
    Write-Host "PSCredential object created successfully."
}

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteMachine -Credential $credential

# Invoke the command on the remote machine using the created PSSession
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { (Get-CimInstance -Class win32_processor -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object Average).Average }

# Close the PSSession
Remove-PSSession $session
```

**Script Description**

> Script attempts to authenticate the user using a Kerberos keytab and a cached credential, and then creates a PowerShell session to the remote machine using the authenticated credentials. Here's an overview of the steps:

1. Set the $env:KRB5CCNAME environment variable to the path of the Kerberos cache file.
2. Use the klist command to list the contents of the Kerberos cache.
3. Use the kinit command to obtain a ticket-granting ticket (TGT) using the user's keytab file.
4. Read the contents of the Kerberos cache file and convert it to a base64-encoded string.
5. Extract the ticket bytes from the base64-encoded string and convert them to a SecureString object.
6. Create a PSCredential object using the user's principal name and the SecureString.
7. Use the New-PSSession cmdlet to create a PowerShell session to the remote machine using the PSCredential object.
8. Use the Invoke-Command cmdlet to execute the desired command on the remote machine.
9. Use the Remove-PSSession cmdlet to close the PowerShell session.

**Error:**

> New-PSSession : [remotemachine.domain.com] Connecting to remote server remotemachine.domain.com failed with
> the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**Question:**

> I am uncertain whether what I am attempting is possible. The Kerberos
> service ticket has been successfully generated and stored in the
> KRB5Cache file. However, I am unsure whether the Kerberos ST ticket
> can be used to create PowerShell credentials since PSCredential only
> accepts a username and password argument. I am uncertain whether it
> will accept the Kerberos ticket as the second argument. I obtained
> part of the code from ChatGPT, and although it is a common use case, I
> have not found any useful samples on the internet.
>
> **Please confirm whether the approach I am taking to authenticate the
> user using the Kerberos ticket is correct or if it is impossible?**
>
> ***Also, please let me know if there is an easier way to obtain the CPU
> usage of a Windows remote machine cluster.Could someone***

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetChars($ticketBytes)` to see if those are giving you the correct chars?

Comment: From my understanding you can simply do `Get-Content $cachePath -Encoding Byte | % { $secureString.AppendChar($_) }` there is no need for those extra steps converting to b64 then converting back then using a specific encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!

Do you mean this,

`$cacheContent = Get-Content $cachePath -Encoding Byte | % { $secureString.AppendChar($_) }`

Can I directly use the cacheContent in the PSCredential

`$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userPrincipal, $cacheContent)`

**I didn't know that it was possible to use the Kerberos service ticket in the PSCredential function.**

Comment: No I meant `$securestring = [securestring]::new(); Get-Content $cachePath -Encoding Byte | % { $secureString.AppendChar($_) }; $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userPrincipal, $securestring)`

Comment: This is the updated code,

`$cachePath = $env:KRB5CCNAME

$securestring = [securestring]::new(); Get-Content $cachePath -Encoding Byte | % { $secureString.AppendChar($_) }

$userPrincipal = "$UserID@$Domain.XXXX.COM" 

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userPrincipal, $secureString)`

Getting this error,

New-PSSession : [remotemachine.domain.com] Connecting to remote server remotemachine.domain.com failed with
the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic