# Has anyone successfully implemented PowerShell remoting using authentication methods other than password-based, particularly Kerberos?

Tags: java, powershell, kerberos, credentials, powershell-remoting

Our objective is to use Kerberos-based authentication for Remote PowerShell in order to execute commands on a remote machine and retrieve the CPU usage.

We intend to execute a PowerShell script from a Java web application using the CreateProcessAsUser function. In order to run the script within the user context, we plan to utilize the CreateProcessAsUser Windows API function via JNA.

Our plan is to utilize a Keytab file and Krb5Cache file to obtain a valid Kerberos ticket for the currently logged-in user. This will enable us to fetch the ST ticket for the user who run the PowerShell Script.

Thus far, obtaining the Kerberos Service ticket using a Keytab file and Krb5Cache file seems feasible. However, the challenge lies in creating a PowerShell credential object using the Kerberos Service ticket. It appears that we cannot use credentials such as Kerberos or GSSCredential directly in PowerShell, and the only option is to utilize the PsCredential function, which solely accepts a username and password. Although ChatGPT suggests using a Base64 encoded Kerberos Ticket as the second argument, this approach does not seem to work.

Is it possible to pass a Kerberos Service Ticket in PsCredential function? Can you please confirm if I am missing anything?

I am trying to fetch the CPU usage of the remote machines in a Windows workstation cluster before running the actual workflow script using SSH.

**How can we achieve PowerShell remoting without requiring a password for each PS-Session or communication, given that every PS authentication method, except for Kerberos, requires a password? It's important to note that the Default Windows Kerberos Ticket cannot be accessed by all logged-in users as it's protected by Windows LSASS, and the only way to generate a Kerberos ticket is through a Keytab file. Furthermore, we have explored all possible options to accomplish this.**

I have attached a PowerShell script that has successfully generated a Kerberos ticket. However, I am unsure whether the **PSCredential will accept the Kerberos ST ticket as the second argument. Can someone please confirm this**?

[PowerShell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841963/powershell-remoting-with-kerberos-authentication-keytab-based)

Comment: What version of Windows?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel  I think issue is with the version of windows you are using.  What error are you getting.  Are you using Net or Core?

Comment: Not sure about which windows version you are asking. Running PowerShell script on Windows 10 machine and the remote machines also the same. Generating Kerberos ticket using Keytab file is part of PowerShell script. Java Web Application (JDK 11) is invoking the PowerShell Script using CreateProcessAsUser Windows API function.

Comment: Wasn't sure which version of windows you were using  Most likely your issue is a proxy enabled.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell on Windows does not deal with Kerberos directly – it uses the SSPI interface provided by Windows. In SSPI, only *Windows itself* is in charge of acquiring all tickets; instead of a file-based keytab, the Kerberos TGT is acquired using the username and password that must be either given to LSASS at logon time, or given to SSPI afterwards.

So in addition to CreateProcessAsUser(), you'd need to use LogonUser() and specify the account's password; the newly created "logon session" will automatically have Kerberos credentials associated with it.

But it is also possible to give a password credential to 'Enter-PSSession'; as long as the username is in `user@REALM` format, SSPI will acquire Kerberos tickets for it. This would be a better solution in general.

```
$cred = [PSCredential]::new("foo@AD.EXAMPLE.COM", $passwd)
Enter-PSSession $host -Credential $cred -Authentication Kerberos
```

(It is also possible to store the password in Windows Credential Store; SSPI will use the stored usernames and passwords to acquire tickets for "foreign" systems. This works even if the client machine is not a domain member.)

Finally, if your application is already running on a domain member system, then it *already has* Kerberos credentials anyway – it doesn't need to specify anything extra. Just configure the Windows service to "log in" as a specific domain user (or if you don't, the service will use the machine credentials) and PowerShell will inherit those credentials automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question with my PowerShell script and included additional information.

As a temporary solution, I am attempting to save the Technical user Credential in the Windows Credentials manager, as per your suggestion. However, when I add it as a Generic Windows Credential, not all users who access the PowerShell script can access it. Is there a way to make it available to all users whoever accessing the PS script?

Comment: No, saved credentials are per-user (and for SSPI it should be added as a Domain credential, not a Generic one). If you want them to live in the script for all users, then put them directly in the script instead of saving them. Why does the script have its own set of credentials in the first place, though?

Comment: I am not interested to hardcode the Credentials directly in the script and the Technical user is not specific to Powershell scirpt. That will be used for multiple purposes in our project. In Windows Credentials Manager, I didn't find 
the the option to create Domain credentials.